# Не выводит ошибку команды kick

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Команда сама работает, но не выводит ошибку о том, что пользователь не указан

```
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages = True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, *, reason = None):

    if member is None:
        emb = discord.Embed(title = '[ERROR] Kick', description = f'{ctx.author.mention}, Укажите пользователя!', color = 0x22ff00)
        emb.add_field(name = 'Пример:', value = f'{ctx.prefix}кик [@участник] [причина]', inline = False)
        emb.add_field(name = 'Пример 1:', value = f'{ctx.prefix}кик @пользователь флуд')
        
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    emb = discord.Embed(title = f'**Кик пользователя**', color = 0x22ff00)
    emb.add_field(name = '**Выдал:**', value = ctx.author.mention, inline = False)
    emb.add_field(name = '**Нарушитель:**', value = member.mention, inline = False)
    emb.add_field(name = '**ID нарушителя:**', value = member.id, inline = False)
    emb.add_field(name = '**Причина:**', value = reason, inline = False)
    await ctx.send(embed = emb)
```

Comment: Нужен `return await ctx.send(embed = emb)` в конце `if member is None:`

Answer (score 0):

```
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages = True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, *, reason = 'Отсутствует'):
    if member is None:
        emb = discord.Embed(title = '[ERROR] Kick', description = f'{ctx.author.mention}, Укажите пользователя!', color = 0x22ff00)
        emb.add_field(name = 'Пример:', value = f'{ctx.prefix}кик [@участник] [причина]', inline = False)
        emb.add_field(name = 'Пример 1:', value = f'{ctx.prefix}кик @пользователь флуд')
        await ctx.send(embed=emb)
        return
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    emb = discord.Embed(title = f'**Кик пользователя**', color = 0x22ff00)
    emb.add_field(name = '**Выдал:**', value = ctx.author.mention, inline = False)
    emb.add_field(name = '**Нарушитель:**', value = member.mention, inline = False)
    emb.add_field(name = '**ID нарушителя:**', value = member.id, inline = False)
    emb.add_field(name = '**Причина:**', value = reason, inline = False)
    await ctx.send(embed = emb)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]